# Incluir salto de línea en json para AWS

Tags: python-3.x, aws

Estoy creando una función lambda en AWS con Python y no puedo incluir un salto de línea en la respuesta: al usar el Test Bot no me reconoce el `\n`, si no que lo escribe tal cual ""Acceso permitido a: \nSilvia"

¿Sabéis si hay manera de poder incluirlo?

Esto es el trozo dentro de la función, donde quiero incluir el salto de línea, en el cuerpo del Json:

```
body = { 
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "Acceso permitido a: \n" + nombre
        }
    }
}
```

Aún no lo he implementado con ningún canal, solo pruebas en el Test de AWS.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso que pones no es una función lambda (al menos no lo que python llama una función lambda). Es un JSON, y en el JSON no están permitidas operaciones entre cadenas. Lo que intentas hacer es equivalente a poner `"content": "Acceso permitido a: \nnombre"` aunque sospecho que esto no va a producir el resultado esperado porque te imprimirá nombre literalmente y no tomado de una variable. Realmente no entiendo qué intentas hacer (quizás porque no sé mucho de las lambda de AWS)

Comment: Eso no es Python.

Comment: Es una función lambda en AWS, uso Python pero es en AWS

Comment: ¿ Que significa `no me reconoce \n` ? ¿ Que resultado esperas ? ¿ Que resultado obtienes ? ¿ Cómo estás obteniendo ese resultado ? ¿ Que continene `nombre` ? Por favor, proporciona un [mcve] y consulta [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: quien debe interpretar el salto de linea???

Comment: @Silvi_Sil creo que necesitas scapar la barra: `\\n` se hace con la doble barra.

Comment: @Silvi_Sil poco tiene que ver lo que le pasa a tu json con la funcion lamda y el python verifica y nos cuentas si con la doble barra solucionas...

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a [algunas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250766/236345) [opciones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54541485/236345) que le han funcionado a otros usuarios interactuando con lambda y SNS en AWS, podrías entregarle:

a) un fin de línea escapado `\\n`

```
body = { 
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "Acceso permitido a: \\n" + nombre
        }
    }
}
```

o b) usar el unicode `&#10;`

```
body = { 
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "Acceso permitido a: &#10;" + nombre
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o una sugerencia?

Comment: Las dos cosas porque no tengo tiempo pa irme a la cuenta AWS de la empresa a probar esto, pero hay duda razonable sobre si le puede servir.

Comment: oki oki ahora se ve mejor

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sigue sin hacer salto de línea, escribe tal cual "\\n o &#10;" tal cual.